# Place tag before input text field in search-block-form

Tags: hooks

I would like to add an li tag infront of the input field in the search-block.
Should be possible with hook_form_alter. I've already printed the array containing the search-block-form, but I couldn't find input type text to add a prefix value.

```
function myTheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
     print_r($form); -> no input type text here to add prefix to.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "input" type you are referring to, is actually the element defined inside the array `$form['search_block_form']`,  of `#type` 'textfield'. That's the element that provides the input field when rendered.

In order to add a `<li>` tag in front and back of this input field, try using the properties   `#prefix` and `#suffix`. Also I would suggest creating a custom module for this, avoid using it inside the template.php file. Try the following (haven't tested it myself, though).

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
     $form['search_block_form']['#prefix'] = '<li>';
     $form['search_block_form']['#suffix'] = '</li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Args, now the li wraps and div. inside that theres a label followed by the input i want the li to be placed :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following what you are saying. You want to add <li> to a label, not to the actual textfield (input) field? If so, just add $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = '<li>My cool label</li>';  (BTW this #title property adds the content inside the <label> tag)

Comment: No no :) It should look like <li></li><input type=text>.....

Comment: Then you want to override search-block-form.tpl.php. But I wonder if it would be easier to just do this with css, you know, as in     display: list-item;     list-style-type: disc; for one of the classes there

Comment: of course, but i need a none css fallback..thanks anyway

Comment: Then go for overriding the search-block-form.tpl.php . I'd be nice if you could mark my answer as correct, also.